# Developer Documentation has gone in xcode 3.2.5?

Tags: xcode

I used to looking up classes/methods from Help->Developer Documentation, which has API doc in local. But after I just upgraded my xcode to 3.2.5, it becomes totally different. When I type something in the search box (e.g. NSString), it accesses the network slowly and asks my developer account/password.

The even worse thing is after I type the password it keeps saying, 
"You Request Is Being Redirected: You may have used an outdated link or typed the address (URL) incorrectly. If you came to this page via a bookmark, please update it accordingly. "

What happened with it? How to get the old Developer Documentation back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happened to me with an earlier update, 2-3 versions before the official iOS 4.2 SDK. You can easily get it back from your **Xcode preferences > Documentation** (all the way to the right side)

Comment: Thank you. I see a list of doc. But all of them are in the status of Getting.

Comment: Pascal's solution works well. What I have to do is waiting for XCode finish downloading.